# SKCanvas copy region

Tags: skiasharp

Having two SKCanvasView (CanvasA and CanvasB):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
       <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasA" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
           <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasB" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
       </Grid>
   </ContentPage.Content>
```

I would like to draw a bitmap onto **CanvasA** and then, by specifying screen coordinates, copy that region of **CanvasA** onto **CanvasB**. This could be achieved by cropping the bitmap drawed onto **CanvasA** on specified coordinates and saving it. Later, load that image and draw it onto **CanvasB**. The problem is that this procedure is very slow, so I would like to know if there is a faster one.

This process must be done on real time, that is why I'm concerned about the process speed.

Comment: think about using 1 canvas instead of 2, even if it will be larger. you will save a lot of cpu-gpu resources.